# Run a command only once in a for loop in Bash

Tags: bash, for-loop, iteration

I have the following pattern of bash code from a function:

```
for folder in ${FOLDER[@]}; do
    if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then
        rsync -rvh --delete-after ${folder} ${folder_dest}
    else
        local zipFile=$(stamp-files file.zip)
        unzip -q ${zipFile} "${folder}"*  -d "${folder_src}"
        rsync -rvh --delete-after ${folder_src}${folder} ${folder_dest}
        rsync -rvh --delete-after ${folder_src}${folder} ${folder_dest2}
    fi
done
```

So in this function I have an if statement in a for loop. And as you can see in the else part there is a call to another function `stamp-files`. This call to the others functions is needed just in the first iteration and even if it is not causing any issue, it could be definitely improved by just calling it once.

Do you know how could I do that simply and keeping that shape of code (the if statement in the for loop)?

Comment: Are you sure you can / want to execute `files=$(stamp-files ${folder})` only once? `rsync ...` depends on `$files` which depends on the loop variable `$folder`. It seems like `$files` should be updated in each iteration.

Comment: Good point, but yes I want to execute it once only. I just tried to show only what is needed for my issue. I just edit the function, hope it make more sense now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set a variable and change it in the first iteration:

```
first='yes'
for folder in "{folders[@]}"; do
    if [[ $first == 'yes' ]]; then
        local files=$(stamp-files "$folder")
        rsync -rvh --delete-after "$files" "$folder_dest"
        first='no'
    else
        rsync -rvh --delete-after "$folder" "$folder_dest"
    fi
done
```

The way you tried to use `$#` wouldn't work: that's the number of positional parameters and has nothing to do with the iteration number or similar.

I've also changed a few things:

- `folders` instead of `FOLDER`; uppercase variable names are more likely to clash with shell and environment variables
- All expansions quoted to prevent word splitting and globbing (the left-hand side in `[[...]]` is automatically quoted)
- I use `$folder` instead of `${folder}`, but that's really just personal taste

Comment: I am using `$#` to distinguish between two different scenarios by adding or not a parameter when I call my function when I need to get into the else part. That is only the reason I am using it. It is not relative to the iteration

Comment: Finally as Benjamin W. proposed I just created an extra variable `stampFiles` to handle this as simple as adding `local stampFiles="yes"` before the for loop, then in the else part add a new if statement as following `if [[ $stampFiles == "yes" ]]; then ... local stampFiles="done"
            fi`
Thank to all for your helps ! :)

Comment: @Benjamin W. Lovely.. exactly what I was searching for

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep structure of your for loop and inside if :

```
unset stamp_files_done
for folder in ${FOLDER[@]}; do
    if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then
        rsync -rvh --delete-after ${folder} ${folder_dest}
    else
        if [[ -z ${stamp_files_done+x} ]]; then local files=$(stamp-files ${folder}); stamp_files_done=""; fi
        rsync -rvh --delete-after ${files} ${folder_dest}
    fi
done
```

---

You could also explain overall task to have more accurate solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know you've said you'd like to keep the shape of the code, but stylistically I'm always hesitant to structure code with an `if` inside a loop just to handle the first element of an array - I prefer to hoist the code out to emphasise that the first element is being treated specially. The other option is to add a state variable, which never makes code any clearer.

In your case, how about

```
if [ ${#FOLDER[@]} -ne 0 ]; then
    local files=$(stamp-files ${FOLDER[0]})
    rsync -rvh --delete-after ${files} ${folder_dest}
    for folder in ${FOLDER[@]:1}; do
        rsync -rvh --delete-after ${folder} ${folder_dest}
    done
fi
```